# How can I web-scrape real time captions from google meet, Using python

Tags: python, google-chrome, web, web-scraping

I want to extract the live captions from google meet, using python.
I tried searching a lot and found some extensions which arent open-source, and if they are, they are not built using python.
This is a serious problem any help would be appreciated a lot.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you use the  pytesseract to get text from an image. Then you can use PIL to take a screen shot. You can repeat this in a while loop.
Once you have taken the screenshot, you can crop it to the text once again using PIL.

Some example code would be:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pytesseract
import time

Lines = []      #Will store text

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files(x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"    #Or wherever your tesseract exe is stored

i = 0
while(i < 10):                      #Loop until you want to stop   
    image = ImageGrab.grab()        #Take screen shot

    width, height = image.size      #Get width and height

    left = 0                        #Variables for cropping
    top = 0
    right = width
    bottom = height

    image = image.crop((left,top,right,bottom))         #Crop image

    image_to_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)  #Get text from image


    #append text to lines
    if(len(Lines) > 0):
        if(Lines[len(Lines)-1] != image_to_text):
            Lines.append(image_to_text)
    else:
        Lines.append(image_to_text)

    i+=1

print(str(Lines)) </code>
```

You may need some slightly different code because the words on Google Meet appear one at once.

I found it difficult to install pytesseract so take care when doing so.

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.